# Как вставить правильно в код JSON

Tags: wordpress, json, acf

есть такой код для вордпресс построенного на ACF

```
'link' => get_the_permalink(),
        'desc' => str_replace('<?xml encoding=\"utf8\" ?>', '', get_sub_field('desc')),
        'poster' => the_field ('????'), - вот здесь беда
        'id_film' => get_field('id_сinema'),
```

А мне картинку нада вставить что бы была постером

```
<?php if( get_field('image') ): ?>
<img src="<?php the_field('image'); ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

И если я просто вставвляю

poster' => get_field ('poster'), то пишет все на свете и автора и размеры и вообще все

Если вставляю poster' => the_field ('poster'), - то код рушит почему то JSON и в самом верху начинает писать путь к картинкам

Comment: Частично решил вопрос только не знаю как     <?php $image = get_field('poster'); if( !empty($image) ): ?>
        <?php
        $kinoafishaid[] = array(
            'poster' => the_field('poster'),
            // echo $image['url'];
        ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

Comment: <?php $image = get_field('poster'); if( !empty($image) ): ?>
        <?php
        $kinoafishaid[] = array(
            'poster' -> $image['url'],
        ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?> вот так поставил но не выводит постера.. ЧТо может быть?

Comment: Покажите полный пример. Я так понял вы просто делаете массив а потов возвращаете JSON? Вам не подойдет the_field т.к. он выводит поле, а не возвращает его.

Comment: Да решение было очень простым оказывается. Не виелд на URL